# NASM output for .bin files

Tags: x86, kernel, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I'm trying to write basic OS kernel on NASM, and I wonder how to produce basic output in flat binary. I already know about int 10h, but I'm reading [this tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones_with_NASM) (I'm not following it, just browsing) and I see it has no such kind (int 10h) of output. I've tried printing string directly to video memory, but it didn't worked and probably you know some alternatives to that command?

P.S. Sorry if question sounds dumb, I'm almost completly new to assembly.

Comment: You _are_ aware the page you linked isn’t a _complete_ standalone tutorial, but goes in conjunction with [Bare Bones](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones), right? It the very fist sentence at the top of the page.

Comment: Well, I think that page was created so you could replace GAS with NASM?

Comment: What you want is a real mode bootloader. The tutorial you linked isn't a bootloader tutorial. It is a kernel booted with multiboot (grub) tutorial.

Comment: Search the same wiki for real mode and bootloading. You'll find a bunch of information.

Comment: Is @user123 related to user1234? ;-) I think if you’re, quote, “almost completely new to assembly” you start out with some Hello World, maybe a recursive Fibonacci, stuff you programmed when beginning programming in some _high-level_ programming language, at any rate something, a program that’s still manageable to debug with `gdb`. An OS is definitely too much.

Comment: @Kai No I'm not related to user1234. I am mentioning that the link provided by user1234 is not related to bootloading but to kernel development with the grub bootloader. In fact, I learnt assembly and OS development by writing a real mode bootloader from scratch. It isn't that difficult. BOCHS (a VM software) offers a good real mode debugger because it can single step 16 bits instructions.